# Split string suing combination of string and length

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below, which i want to split using a number and "+", i tried with the below code,

Input String:
    20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407+20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085+20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054+20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345+20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A

Code:

```
First found the len of the string,
var str1 = 20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407+20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085+20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054+20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345+20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A
str2 = str1.length;
if (str2 > '400') {
  var str3 = str1.split("+", 100);
}else{
  var str3 = str1
}
```

Desired Output:

```
str3[0] = 20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407
str3[1] = 20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085
str3[2] = 20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054
str3[3] = 20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345
str3[4] = 20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A
```

Length by default here is 100 and which should decrease based on the string rather than increasing (help need to accomplish this)

Please help me on this with some guidance

Comment: So you want a Maximum of 400 characters in one array, right?

Comment: @TripleEEE   length of char  is 100 which should decrease based in the string.

Comment: `len(str1)` should be `str1.length`

Comment: `str2` is a number so why you're comparing it with the string `'400'`? And why you're calling `.split()` on `str2` (a number which has no `split` method)? And the second parameter in `.split("+", 100)` [restricts the number of returned elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) but not the length of each element in the array.

Comment: @Mahi thanks, Mahi! I corrected that part.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! corrected that part of the code.

Comment: @Andreas—might look bad, but it's not an error. The comparison operators coerce the arguments to number so `399 < '400'` "works".  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost the same as Nina Scholz's answer, but a little different. Starts from 0 then looks for the "+" after the next 100 characters then copies that to the result array. Starts again from the character after the "+" until the string is exhausted.

```js
var s = '20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407+20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085+20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054+20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345+20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A';

var start = 0,
    min = 100,
    pos = 0,
    result = [];
while (pos != -1) {
  pos = s.indexOf('+', start + min);
  result.push(s.substring(start, pos == -1? s.length : pos));
  start = pos+1;
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) with a right start value as `fromIndex` to search for the next `+` and slice the string for the parts.

```js
var string = '20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407+20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085+20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054+20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345+20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A',
    length = 100,
    start = 0,
    pos,
    result = [];

while ((pos = string.indexOf('+', start +  length)) !== -1) {
    result.push(string.slice(start, pos));
    start = pos + 1;
}
result.push(string.slice(start));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for explanation in comments

```js
var s = "20001+20002+20003+20005+20019+20035+20009+20011+20015+20006+20020+20047+20048+20050+20049+204044+22407+20052+20057+20058+20059+20063+20065+20067+20068+20070+20072+20073+20075+20076+20078+20081+20084+20085+20086+20140+21954+206171+206170+206175+20093+206168+206177+206172+20098+206167+20107+20053+20054+20056+20108+20109+20110+20112+20115+20117+20119+20124+20126+20131+20132+20136+20141+20344+20345+20346+20348+20349+20355+20356.A"

var d = [];

var slug = 100;//threshold value for separatuion

var rounds = Math.ceil(s.length/slug); //find how many elemnts shall be formed
console.log(rounds);
for(var i=0;i<rounds;i++){ //loop it
 d.push(s.substr(0,slug)); //extract the basic initial string
//console.log(d,s,s.length) //extract the remaining string for next iteration
s = (s.length > slug) ? s.substr(slug) : s //make sure for last string less than slug value

}

 console.log(d,d.length);
```